NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function
Title: Angular 18: Dynamic Microfrontend Loading with Native Federation - NG0203 Error
Question:
I am trying to dynamically load a microfrontend component in an Angular 18 app using angular native federation and the loadRemoteModule method. The goal is to load a remote module from another Angular app and display it as a custom element (use the remote component so i can pass input and receive events from the component). However, I am encountering the following error:
ERROR RuntimeError: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.dev/errors/NG0203

Here is the code for my setup:
app.component.ts:
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/native-federation';
import { Component, Injector, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMicroFrontend();
  }

  loadMicroFrontend() {
    loadRemoteModule({
      remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.json', // Ensure this matches the remote setup
      remoteName: 'mfe2',
      exposedModule: './ExposeUserName'
    })
    .then((MicroModule: any) => {
      const ce = createCustomElement(MicroModule.ExposedUserNameComponent, {
        injector: this.injector
      });

      if (!customElements.get('app-expose-user-name')) {
        customElements.define('app-expose-user-name', ce);
      }
    })
    .catch((err: any) => console.error('Error loading remote module:', err));
  }
}

app.component.html:
<app-expose-user-name [name]="'John Doe'"></app-expose-user-name>

Problem:

I am getting the NG0203 error, which indicates an issue with the inject() function being used outside of an injection context.
I am using Angular 18 and @angular-architects/native-federation for microfrontend integration.
The remote module is being loaded correctly, but the error prevents it from rendering as a custom element.

Question:
How can I resolve the error  NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with runInInjectionContext and show the remote component successfully  in Angular 18?

